# How do I .map() a new array of values from an array and an object?

Tags: javascript

```
let a1 = [1, 3, 5];
let a2 = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: 2,}

// pass a function to map

const map1 = a1.map(? => ?);
console.log(map1);

// expected output: Array ["a", "c", 2]
```

I want the number in the array 1, 3, 5 to map to the values on the keys of a2

What should "? => ?" be for the desired result?

### Edited

My question is after reading the documentation `Array.prototype.map()` in MDN.

My question is (not how to solve this) but to learn about the callback function in `.map()`:

```
let a1 = [1, 3, 5];
let a2 = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: 2,}

// pass a function to map

const map1 = a1.map(a2, e => a2.value);
console.log(map1);

// expected output: Array ["a", "c", 2]
```

Here I wanted e in a1 to match a2 and return a2 in the map function, but it's clearly wrong but after Googling for examples I guess I just had to make a question about it and try not cause too much confusion.

Comment: quiz pro quo ...? is it homework?

Comment: [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144) - Also see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Question that simple post requirements and ask for solution show no effort but expect all the *free* effort from others.

Comment: no its not homework, I was trying to extract the values from a JSON and I boiled it down to this question

Comment: how would you so eloquently formulate the problem where i want the values of an object mapped with an array to a new array @fran? with a poem?

Comment: Instead of asking what to do / you should show some research, too. / Otherwise it needs some luck / to analyze where you are stuck. :D

Comment: Google for some examples, very easy, then give it a shot. If it fails post your code you have issues with preferably in a snippet (Feature in the Question Box) demonstrating the problem (That's actual code instead of `? => ?`). You can write it in a form of  a poem off course, I don't think there is anything in the FAQ against that :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply get the property from the object.

```js
let a1 = [1, 3, 5];
let a2 = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: 2,}

// pass a function to map
const map1 = a1.map(k => a2[k]);
// -----------------^^^^^^^^^^----
console.log(map1);
```